# OpenCV C++ absdiff() unhandled exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I tried finding the frame difference between a still image and a frame taken from my webcam, using `absdiff()`. My code is as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    VideoCapture webcam(0);
    Mat img, web, diff;
    
    webcam >> web;
    img = imread("/Users/dnxv2/Desktop/test.jpg");

    cvtColor(web, web, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(img, img, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    absdiff(img, web, diff);
    
    imshow("test", diff);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Upon running it, I ran into an error, and I could not resolve it.

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF937E24F99 in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000FA29CFE1B0.

Was there something I missed? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: How do you know that absdiff is the source? Please test web and img before usage. One of them might be empty.

Comment: Ah I finally found out why my program got the error, thank you for your help! :D
p/s resolution issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this problem. In short, it was only a small resolution issue, which could be fixed by matching the resolution of `img` with `web`.

Here are the two lines of code that seemed to resolve the issue if anyone is interested :D

```
int resx = 500, resy = 500; // 500x400 resolution
resize(img, img, { resx, resy }, 0, 0, cv::INTER_NEAREST);
resize(web, web, { resx, resy }, 0, 0, cv::INTER_NEAREST);
```